# updateScore not working

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I'm having a problem about my updateScore, my function does is if the user plays the game for the first time.

It will create my file named myFile.txt to record the score, now the code to do that is (if reader then) to see if file exist, if it doesn't, it will go to my **else** if there is already a file then my contents should have a value of the score, then I could use it to compare and get my highscore.

The problem is my contents always returns `nil` value and therefore the score you will always get when you play will replace the score supposed to be my highscore, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
function updateScore()

    local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
    local reader = io.open( path, "r" )
    local file = io.open( path, "w" )

    if reader then

        reader:close()
        local reader1 = io.open( path, "r" )
        local contents = reader1:read("*n")


        if (stopscore == false) then
            score = score + 1
            scoreText.text = "score: " .. score
            scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
            scoreText.x = 0
            scoreText.y = 30
        end

        if (stopscore == true) then

            if (contents == nil) then
                local file = io.open( path, "w" )
                file:write(score)
                file:flush()
                file:close()
                timer.pause(timer1)
                director:changeScene( "menu", "downFlip" )

            else

                if (contents < score) then
                    file:write(score)
                    file:flush()
                    file:close()
                    timer.pause(timer1)
                    director:changeScene( "menu", "downFlip" )
                else
                    file:write(contents)
                    file:flush()
                    file:close()
                    timer.pause(timer1)
                    director:changeScene( "menu", "downFlip" )
                end

            end
        end

    else

        local file1 = io.open( path, "w" )
        local walaVal=0
        file1:write(walaVal)
        file1:close()

        if (stopscore == false) then
            score = score + 1
            scoreText.text = "score: " .. score
            scoreText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)
            scoreText.x = 0
            scoreText.y = 30
            print(contents)
        end

        if (stopscore == true) then
            local file = io.open( path, "w" )
            file:write(score)
            file:flush()
            file:close()
            timer.pause(timer1)
            director:changeScene( "menu", "downFlip" )
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the contents returns nil because the problem occurs on this code 
**`local file = io.open( path, "w" )`** when you call this it will erase all the content of the file to solve this you must remove the the mode "w" when you call local file like this local `file = io.open(path)` and when its time for you to update the score you should put the mode "w" again to further understand what i'm saying i will write and explain the code.

```
--first check the file if exist
   local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
   local file = io.open(path)

-- if file exist check the content and read the score else create a file and write the score

  if file then
      local reader = io.open( path, "r" )
      local contents = reader:read("*n")
-- if content is less than myScore Update the Score
     if contents < myScore then
     file = io.open(path,"w")
     file:write(myScore)
         file:flush()
         file:close()
     end
 else
    file = io.open(path,"w")
    file:write(myScore)
    file:flush()
    file:close()
 end
```

hope i explain it well for you :)